# I want to use a value from a different function *PYTHON*

Tags: python

this is the value im trying to use in a different function

```
def Task1():

    total_titles=0

    for each_book in book_list:

        total_titles = total_titles + float(each_book[5])
        
    print('The total number of book titles available is: ', total_titles)
```

This is the text file that it is reading form labelled book_data_file.txt

```
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

The actual question for the task is make Option to add new book item(which i have already done succesfully and i will put the code at the very bottom if needed for context)  and present a summary report displaying (a) the increase in total number of titles in stock and (b) the cost difference in average price of books in stock

And this is the code i have so far but im not sure what i should do next, because i think im going about it wrong.

```
def Task4a():

    file = open("book_data_file.txt","r")
    line_count = 0
    for line in book_list:
        if line != "\n":
            line_count += 1
    print('The new total number of titles is: ', line_count)

    print(total_titles)
```

The code to add values to the text file is as seen below

```
def Task4():

    print('\nEnter the new book record')
    author = input("Enter the author's name: ")
    title = input("Enter the title name: ")
    format_ = input("Enter the format: ")
    publisher = input("Enter the pubisher name: ")
    cost = input("Enter the price: ")
    stock = input("Enter the amount of stock you would like to add: ")
    genre = input("Enter the genre: ")

    bookrecord = [author, title, format_, publisher, cost, stock, genre]
    book_list.append(bookrecord)
```

Can anyone please help?, i feel like theres an easy solution but im really missing it, Thanks

Comment: Variables from one function are not available in another function. You should use `return` to return values from a function and use them in another function. I suggest looking up a tutorial to explain how that works.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a value from a function using return. For example:

```
def function1(variable1):
   variable2 = variable1 + 1
   return variable1, variable2

variable1, variable2 = function1(2)
```